# how to color listitem in list

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

Hi I am using asp:listbox in my code.

```
  <td>
   <asp:ListBox id="ddlWhereStudy" runat="server" rows="4"></asp:ListBox>
    </td>
```

I want to color the listbox listitem conditionally. Please see the below code:

```
private void FillStudyWhereDropDown()       
{
                  XmlNodeList objNodeList = FinalDoc.SelectNodes("//root/tcm:ListKeywords[@Type='StudyWhere']/child::tcm:Item", namespaceManager);
                  ddlWhereStudy.Items.Clear();
                  ddlWhereStudy.Items.Add(new ListItem(ResourceFile.GetResourceString("c_AdvisorOptionDefault")));
                  for (int i = 0; i < objNodeList.Count; i++)
                  {
                        string[] parts = objNodeList[i].Attributes["Title"].Value.Split('_');
                        ListItem li = new ListItem(parts[1], parts[2]);
                        ddlWhereStudy.Items.Add(li);
                        if (parts[3] == "B")
                        {
                              li.Attributes.Add("Style", "Color: 'RED'");          
                        }
                  }
}
```

Above code is working fine when I am using **select** but it is not working with **asp:ListBox**

Please suggest!

Comment: yes. Plz try. and let me know if there is any problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from this code list item 4 and 8 are red and others have default color

```
for (int count = 0; count < 10; count++)
    {
        ListItem li = new ListItem();
        li.Text = count.ToString();
        li.Value = count.ToString();
        if (count == 4 || count == 8)
        {
            li.Attributes.Add("style", "Color: Red");
        }
        lst.Items.Add(li);
    }
```

Comment: Thank Akhtar, Do it will work in .net 1.1 version as it working fine in 2.0. Please confirm

Comment: I have not checked in 1.1 as I don't have 1.1 version, but I have checked in 2.0 and it is working